# Trying to check and see if a post has a featured image outside of the main loop

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails, get-posts

I've got a situation where I need to find out if the currently loaded post has a featured image, if it does, I want it to display a different logo than if it doesn't have a featured image associated with the post.

This works right now, but doesn't have the check feature I'm looking for:

```
<?php echo is_front_page() ? '<h1 id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">' : '<strong id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">'; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php header_image() ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" /></a>
<?php echo is_front_page() ? '</h1>' : '</strong>'; ?>
```

My issue is that I've looked at the WP documentation for get_posts or starting a new WP_query, but haven't had any luck understanding how I can:

- run a new loop that gets the page ID and sees if it has a featured image
- do a standard if/else statement afterwards

My thinking with the if/else would be like this:

```
<?php echo is_front_page() ? '<h1 id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">' : '<strong id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">'; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow">

    <? // IF/ELSE CODE TO EXECUTE IF post_has_thumbnail ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>      
    <img src="<?php header_image() ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" />
    <?php else : ?>
    <img src="/i/logo-no-feat-img.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo" height="120" width="222" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <? // end ATTEMPTED IF/ELSE CODE ?>

    </a>
<?php echo is_front_page() ? '</h1>' : '</strong>'; ?>
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
    <?php echo is_front_page() ? '<h1 id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">' : '<strong id="logo" class="h1 threecol first">'; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
    <? // IF/ELSE CODE TO EXECUTE IF post_has_thumbnail ?>
    <?php if (is_home() || has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()) ) : ?>      
    <img src="<?php header_image() ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" />
    <?php else : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo-without-feat_img.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> logo" height="302" width="203" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <? // end IF/ELSE CODE ?>
    </a>
    <?php echo is_front_page() ? '</h1>' : '</strong>'; ?>
```

Comment: No need to write whole sentences in bold :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`has_post_thumbnail()` accepts a post ID:

```
if ( is_singular() and has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() )
{
    // show post thumbnail
}
elseif ( is_front_page() )
{
    // show front page content
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps! Can you do an and/or, i.e.:

`if ( is_home() and/or has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() )`

Comment: forgot about the pipes! :D `||`

Comment: @TigerDanky `||` equals `OR`, `&&` equals `AND` and `XOR` equals "and/or".